# can't run docker container with simple node app example in bluemix

Tags: node.js, docker, ibm-cloud

this is a simple node app example, and it works ok in my machine ;-) ,
locally I kick off the container with the script deploy_local.sh, and I get:

```
$ ./deploy_local.sh 
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
Untagged: example:latest
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
Pulling repository registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode
...
Status: Image is up to date for registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.656 kB
...
Successfully built 83d92bb3ff5f
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
flag provided but not defined: -f
See '/usr/bin/docker --help'.
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
OI
$
```

having the image locally I then try to push it to bluemix, successfully:

```
$ ice --local push registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/techdays/example
Target is local host. Invoking docker with the given arguments...
The push refers to a repository [registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/techdays/example] (len: 1)
Sending image list
...
Image 4f7397e97d5c already pushed, skipping
Pushing tag for rev [83d92bb3ff5f] on {https://registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v1/repositories/techdays/example/tags/latest}
$
```

but when I try to run it:

```
$ ice run --name example registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/techdays/example
Command failed with container cloud service
{
    "id": "IC0000", 
    "incident_id": "37295f32b40079a8", 
    "message": "Sorry, an error occurred on our side. Please reference the problem using the provided incident ID.", 
    "name": "DefaultError", 
    "type": "General"
}
$
```

has anyone experienced this ?

my tools versions:

```
$ ice version
ICE CLI Version        : 2.0.1 271 2015-03-30T15:40:18
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef
```

-- dockerfile --

```
FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD dist /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

-- app.js --

```
console.log('OI');
```

-- deploy_local.sh --

```
#!/bin/sh
CONTAINER_NAME=example
REGISTRY=registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
ORG=techdays
ice --local pull $REGISTRY/ibmnode
ice --local build -t $CONTAINER_NAME .
ice --local -f tag $CONTAINER_NAME $REGISTRY/$ORG/$CONTAINER_NAME
ice --local run $CONTAINER_NAME
```

Comment: If all that app.js does is log one thing, won't that be considered a problem since the process exits almost immediately? And what is `flag provided but not defined: -f` about?

Comment: ...the -f was intended to force the tagging of the image, but locally it does not have any effect for we actually get the output of the container:
OI
...anyway if it is not a problem why did the command failed?

Comment: just changed the app to an express server printing the same log message and same result.  Have to say that I had created a new space for this testing example, but now I've changed back to my previous space, and built and kicked off the container and... it worked! Something strange with the spaces there, clueless, doesn't help to have those error messages, not a single clue of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update ICE and docker versions.
For Bluemix container you need ICE version 3 and docker 1.6.2 or 1.7.

See [this document](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ice_ov.html#container_cli_ice_install) for more details and links to install the recommended versions of the tools.

Answer (score 1):

according to the error message, it seems a temporary problem with container enviroment.
Is it still not working or is it solved right now?

Comment: hello, thanks for being there :-)
still getting:
 "id": "IC0000", 
 "incident_id": "ec911eb8867e8b57"